# Constant time binning of values

Tags: algorithm, classification

Say I have a vector of values that represent the upper boundaries of classes to classify (bin) values in. So e.g. vector { 1, 3, 5, 10 } represents bins [0, 1[, [1, 3[, [3, 5[ and [5,10[. How do I implement classification of a random value V in one of these classes (0,1,2,3) in constant time? It's trivial to walk the list of boundaries and stop once V surpasses the bin's upper boundary; but that's O(n) wrt the number of bins; I'm looking to do this in constant time.

I thought it was trivial before I was actually typing the code, by setting up a lookup table, dividing each V by a certain value depending on the class bounds and then using the (rounded) result of the division to find the bin number in the lookup table. But I'm finding it a lot harder than I thought to made this in a generic way that minimizes the size of the lookup table while still being accurate, regardless of the proportional distance between bin boundaries; and in a way that works for all real values. With Google'ing I only find algorithms that determine the boundaries of the bins, at least using the terms I did.

Comment: If this is really a question about random sampling, search Google for the alias method.

Comment: I just learnt the reversed square bracket also indicates an excluded element. It's pretty painful to look at if they're next to each other like that (compared to `[0, 1)`, which would mean the same).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a way to do this in strictly constant time (and not requiring infinite space) without taking advantage of some property of the given numbers.

---

A lookup table is a decent idea, but floating point values makes this difficult. If the number of digits is finite, you can consider is having the **lookup table represented as essentially a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** (a tree where each level represents a digit).

So for `{1, 2.5, 5, 9}`, your tree would look something like this:

```
                              root
  /   /          /          /  |  \   \   \   \   \
 0   1          2          3   4   5   6   7   8   9
          /     |     \
       2.0 ... 2.5 ... 2.9
```

Each leaf node would contain a value indicating which interval it belongs to, so
0 will be set to 0,
1, 2.0 - 2.4 will all be set to 1,
2.5 - 2.9, 3 - 4 will be set to 2,
5 - 9 will be set to 3

A query would just involve starting from the root and repeatedly going to the child node corresponding to the next digit in the number we're looking up (if you look up 2.65 in the above tree, you first go to 2, then 2.6, then, since it's a leaf, you stop and return it's value, which is 1).

The time complexity for a query would be `O(d)`, where `d` is the number of significant digits in your vector, and the space complexity is `O(nd)`.

That might not sound particularly efficient, but keep in mind that `d` is the number of *digits* - for example, that would be `d = log m` with `m` being the maximum possible value if we're talking about positive integers.

---

`O(log n)` is fairly trivial if you just set up **a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)** (BST) containing all the values in the vector mapped to their original indices.

A lookup would look very similar to how you'd search a BST - start from the root and go either left or right until you find the value, except in this case you note every node you visit and return the mapped index of the closest value that's not bigger. Some API's have methods that basically do this for you (such as `std::map` in C++).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get O(1) is to create a lookup table so that you can look up all the values directly.

This is only feasable if the boundaries are behaving nicely:

1. The expected numbers are integers or the boundaries are integers or have limited precision. This allows you to round down (floor) the number before checking against the lookup table and drastically reduces the required entries for the table.
2. The difference between the max and min boundary cannot be too big. Let's say we know that the precision of the boundaries is 0.5 and the min is 1 and the max is 10, then the lookup table requires (10-1)/0.5 = 18 entries.

The checks for the first and last group (smaller than min and greater than max) is done with simple if checks which doesn't affect the complexity.